# Error when try to Import Library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a project with blank activity. I want to import a library to my project. I tried to import via File -> New -> Import Module. But I got an error like this :

*Error:No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer*

This is library that I want to import : 
https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

I hope you can help me. Thank You.

Comment: First link on _youtube_: [How to use/import library in Android Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7sHAYYubJo)

Answer (score 0):

In android studio, open app gradle & synchronize it. It should work.

**App Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
}
```

**Usage**

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that's not work. Help me please, I'm beginner in android

Comment: Hello bro, I tried that in my project & got no error. please open app gradle not project gradle. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I open app gradle not project gradle. Please tell how to import that library. Thanks before.

Comment: In app gradle, In dependecies between the curly brackets, paste   :  compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'    & synchronize  the projects & you are done.

Comment: I imported this gradle  don't have any error, please check you are adding gradle in dependencies of app level not of project level...
if you still get error please describe it

Comment: I will try it tomorrow. Thanks Adnanul and Amit Bhati for the answer